# BasicDBObject update duplicate same document

Tags: java, mongodb, updates, upsert

I have a big problem with the api java mongodb. I use a request with the update methods of DBCollection class and in the mongodb i get a multiple same document while the value doesn't change,help me please. I don't want to have a duplicate document.

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.append("ad", "man2ist").append("list.id", new BasicDBObject("$ne", "5")); //  "list.id" : {$ne : 0 }

BasicDBObject a = new BasicDBObject("id",String.valueOf(5)).append("value", 100);
BasicDBObject upd = new BasicDBObject("$addToSet",new BasicDBObject("list",a));
System.out.println(query);

System.out.println(upd);

WriteResult r = dbc.update(query,upd,true,false);

//db.friends.update({ "ad" : "man2ist" , "list.id" : { $ne : "4"} },{ $addToSet : { "list" : { "id" : "4","value" : 100}}},true,true);
```

my document here :

```
{
"ad" : "man2ist",
"createdDate" : ISODate(),
"list" : [
        {
                "id" : "45",
                "value" : 489
        },
        {
                "id" : "5",
                "value" : 20,

        },
        {
               "id" : "4578",

                "value" : 21,

        } ]}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do and how documents of your collection look like?

Comment: with the mongo shell in the terminal, that's work but with mongo java driver when i update a document with the upsert option i get a duplicate document. Maybe it's a bug in java mongo driver but it's not normally. I want update my document, if is already exist i dont't create but i update him, if he don't exist i create him, thanks.

Comment: Before going for possible bug in java driver (it is not excluded), can you explain in plain english which document you want to update. I mean the condition that the document should satisfiedto be updated. Sometime the problem is just is mistyping of an operator, especially when your operation works with one driver and not with other.

Comment: for the document look my first post, i updated him, also here is my mongo request : db.friends.update( {ad: "man2ist", "list.id" : {$ne : "5" }} , {$addToSet : {"list" : {'id' : "5" , 'value' : 100 }} } ,true , false);. Everything works fine in the mongo shell but not in java. Above i have one json document if i want update him, i get two same document with different oid (object_id). I feel that it can not find the document and therefore it create another

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you set the upset flag to true, meaning that the document should be created if no document matching the criteria is found. If there is no document matching the criteria in the db, the mongo shell will do the same.

If you change your query to this,

```
WriteResult r = dbc.update(query,upd,false,false);
```

it should work all the time.

Comment: Yes but if the document does not exist mongo does not create. In addition my search criterion is correct, as you can see ("ad" : "man2ist" ) , but I feel it does not recognize. I want to say it works perfectly with mongo shell.

Comment: I have tried, and even the mongo shell create a new doc if one matching the criteria does not exist. For your criteria, everything is correct. Maybe you should try the query in an empty collection to see. Change the collection name to friendstest that does no exist and run the command in the mongo shell again to see. db.friendstest.update( {ad: "man2ist", "list.id" : {$ne : "5" }} , {$addToSet : {"list" : {'id' : "5" , 'value' : 100 }} } ,true , false). After that, the collection friendstest will have a new doc.

Comment: If I use the mongo shell with my query where the upsert option is false and that an empty collection, it creates me a document. If the document exists it puts me to update my data. By cons in java, if I reuse the same query on an empty collection, it nothing happens, I am forced to turn the upsert option but then there is the problem of duplicate document . I think I will proceed in two stages, first with the creation of the doc and insert the second update with upsert and update to false.

Comment: I use the jongo java framework for mongodb and everything works fine, I find the same operation with the shell, thanks.